# How to MySQL SELECT and order by a column and sort by another key in a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, group-by

I am building a pretty simple web app to check to see if a website is available (returns a http 200 code) using a cURL call. I need to get the domains to be checked which I currently have a SELECT *.  I was told it needs to be sorted by the domain_key(last_checked) with a corresponding domain_key which has a timestamp.  This way we can check the domain with the oldest last_checked value. The first table has these columns:

`ID | CREATED | DOMAIN | accountID | server | status`

Then I have a details table:

`ID | domainID | domain_key | domain_value`

I was also told to process the requests by server?  So my question is:

How can I order or group the domains by server?  Is that possible to do in one query or would I need to have separate SELECT statements for each group of domains on a particular server?

Comment: what is the connection between these two tables? Is domain of table 1 equal to domainID of table 2? What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes.  domainID is a foreign key and is the primary key of the domain table.  I know I can use a join statement to order them by last_checked, but I am wondering how to group them by the server with the oldest last checked at the top of each server group

Comment: You mean table1.ID = table2.domainID and not table1.domain = table2.domainID, right? Please edit your query to add the SQL JOIN with table names etc. Also, what do you mean by "oldest last checked"? Which field are you referring to?

Comment: This:

select domain, server, (select max(convert(domain_value, datetime)) from details where
           domainID = domains.id and domain_key = 'last_checked') as last_checked
           from domains group by domain, server;

Answer (score 0):

select domain, server, (select max(convert(domain_value, datetime)) from details where
           domainID = domains.id and domain_key = 'last_checked') as last_checked
           from domains group by domain, server;

Answer (score 0):

Does this serve your purpose?

```
select domain, server, 
(select max(convert(domain_value, datetime)) from details 
where domainID = domains.id and domain_key = 'last_checked') as last_checked 
from domains order by server, last_checked desc
```